# A console application to get a web page resource, using c# (javascript may cause this)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping

Aim: To download a website source with using a console application. You can find the used class in the program below.

Question: I use the code below to download a data (source) of a web page. Imagine you use chrome; If you enter first this query string, the web page itself redirects you a view HTML page and you see the data.

1. Entering this URL, to show the results it redirects itself to second page below. I make it by using javascript.

www.xyz.com/aaa.html?search=aaa&id=1

2. it redirects here: www.xyz.com/ViewResult.html

In an explorer, It works fine . I see 4 HTML tables inside the page when I use google chrome view source option. Bu in my application I see only two tables of the 4 . The two tables inside the web page is missing.(the missing two tables are the second and third.)

How can I overcome to this problem? I want to get the source of the page as I see in chrome.

Bonus informations: There is no iframe.

The particular Code :

```
  string url = "www.xyz.com/aaa.html?search=aaa&id=1";
   WebPage  pG = ss.RequestPage(url, "", "GET");

    pG = ss.RequestPage("www.xyz.com/ViewResult.html");

    string source= pG.Html;


 public WebPage RequestPage(Uri url, string content, string method, string contentType)
        {
            string htmlResult;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] contentData = encoding.GetBytes(content);

            request.Proxy = Proxy;
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.Method = method;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // false
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Referer = LastUrl;
            request.KeepAlive = true; //false,

            request.UserAgent = UserAgent;

            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            //request.Headers.Add("UA-CPU", "x86");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");

            String cookieString = "";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> cookiePair in Cookies)
                cookieString += cookiePair.Key + "=" + cookiePair.Value + ";";

            if (cookieString.Length > 2)
            {
                String cookie = cookieString.Substring(0, cookieString.Length - 1);
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
            }

            if (method == "POST")
            {
                request.ContentLength = contentData.Length;
                request.ContentType = contentType;

                Stream contentWriter = request.GetRequestStream();
                contentWriter.Write(contentData, 0, contentData.Length);
                contentWriter.Close();
            }

            int attempts = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response == null)
                        throw new WebException();

                    break;
                }
                catch (WebException)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                        response.Close();

                    if (attempts == PageReattempts)
                    {
                       throw;  
                    }
                    else { }

                    // Wait three seconds before trying again
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);

                }

                attempts += 1;
            }

            // Tokenize cookies
            if (response.Headers["Set-Cookie"] != null)
            {
                String headers = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Replace("path=/,", ";").Replace("HttpOnly,", "");
                foreach (String cookie in headers.Split(';'))
                {
                    if (cookie.Contains("="))
                    {
                        String[] splitCookie = cookie.Split('=');
                        String cookieKey = splitCookie[0].Trim();
                        String cookieValue = splitCookie[1].Trim();

                        if (Cookies.ContainsKey(cookieKey))
                            Cookies[cookieKey] = cookieValue;
                        else
                            Cookies.Add(cookieKey, cookieValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Cookies.ContainsKey(cookie))
                            Cookies[cookie] = "";
                        else
                            Cookies.Add(cookie, "");
                    }
                }
            }

            htmlResult = ReadResponseStream(response);
            response.Close();

            if (response.Headers["Location"] != null)
            {
                response.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                String newLocation = response.Headers["Location"];
                WebPage result = RequestPage(newLocation);
                return new WebPage(result.Html, new WebPage(htmlResult));
            }

            LastUrl = url.ToString();

            return new WebPage(htmlResult);
        }
```

Comment: Far as I can tell, JavaScript will not be processed at all with your approach. Any JavaScript that changes the page will not execute and the page will be different. – Christopher Wirt 9 hours ago   @christopher-wirt  do you have any other suggestion to make an a proper aproach? please.

Comment: You could use phantom.js or a similar product to get the source of your page. See `content` property provided by phantom.js: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Welcome to web-scrapping club. In cases like this I often try to use Fiddler to record requests set by browser to server, if they are repeatable I try to simulate then using HttpClient. Since you don't specify original URL I can only tell you that generally you must behave like a browser, send proper User-Agent, keep cookies, in case of Ajax Request add appropriate X-Requested-With header. Instead of executing JS try to figure out how this url is generated it is taken from some hidden inputs or is it generated from some hardcoded variable, and repeat that code in your program.

Comment: @csharpfolk would you mail me please about your email: mine is: blgnklc {at} gmail. com thanks in advance. congrats on your win today ))

Comment: Hey, if you're open towards switching to _python_ to scrape the web pages, [this](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/) might work out for you.

Answer (score 2):

1-WebBrowser :

```
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{
    public ExtendedWebBrowser()
    {
        // Ensure that ScriptErrorsSuppressed is set to false.
        this.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        this.ProgressChanged += ExtendedWebBrowser_ProgressChanged;
    }

    private void ExtendedWebBrowser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // InjectAlertBlocker();
        string alertBlocker = @"window.alert = function () { }; 
                        window.print = function () { }; 
                        window.open = function () { }; 
                        window.onunload = function () { }; 
                        window.onbeforeunload = function () { };";
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        webBrowser?.Document?.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { alertBlocker, "JavaScript" });
        this.Document?.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { alertBlocker, "JavaScript" });
    }

    public void NavigationWaitToComplete(string url)
    {
        bool complete = false;
        NavigationAsync(url).ContinueWith((t) => complete = true);
        while (!complete)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
    public void NavigationWaitToComplete(string url, string targetFrameName, byte[] postData, string additionalHeaders)
    {
        bool complete = false;
        NavigationAsync(url, targetFrameName, postData, additionalHeaders).ContinueWith((t) => complete = true);
        while (!complete)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
    public async Task NavigationAsync(string url, string targetFrameName, byte[] postData, string additionalHeaders)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsNavigation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); ;
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsDocument = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); ;

        Navigated += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (tcsNavigation.Task.IsCompleted)
                return;
            tcsNavigation.SetResult(true);
        };

        DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                return;
            if (tcsDocument.Task.IsCompleted)
                return;
            tcsDocument.SetResult(true);
        };

        Navigate(url, targetFrameName, postData, additionalHeaders);
        await tcsNavigation.Task;
        // navigation completed, but the document may still be loading

        await tcsDocument.Task;
        // the document has been fully loaded, you can access DOM here

    }
    public async Task NavigationAsync(string url)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsNavigation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); ;
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsDocument = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); ;

        Navigated += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (tcsNavigation.Task.IsCompleted)
                return;
            tcsNavigation.SetResult(true);
        };

        DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                return;
            if (tcsDocument.Task.IsCompleted)
                return;
            tcsDocument.SetResult(true);
        };

        Navigate(url);
        await tcsNavigation.Task;
        // navigation completed, but the document may still be loading

        await tcsDocument.Task;
        // the document has been fully loaded, you can access DOM here

    }
}
```

Calling:

```
var browser = new ExtendedWebBrowser();
        browser.NavigationWaitToComplete("www.xyz.com/aaa.html?search=aaa&id=1");
var html = browser.Document.Body.OuterHtml();
```

2-CefSharp.OffScreen

```
private async Task<string> RequestPageAsync(string url, string cachePath, double zoomLevel)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        //Reduce rendering speed to one frame per second so it's easier to take screen shots
        browserSettings.WindowlessFrameRate = 1;
        var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = cachePath };
        // RequestContext can be shared between browser instances and allows for custom settings
        // e.g. CachePath
        using (var requestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings))
        using (var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url, browserSettings, requestContext))
        {
            if (zoomLevel > 1)
            {
                browser.FrameLoadStart += (s, argsi) =>
                {
                    var b = (ChromiumWebBrowser)s;
                    if (argsi.Frame.IsMain)
                    {
                        b.SetZoomLevel(zoomLevel);
                    }
                };
            }
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += (s, argsi) =>
            {
                var b = (ChromiumWebBrowser)s;
                if (argsi.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    b.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
                    {
                        tcs.TrySetResult(taskHtml.Result);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
        return tcs.Task.Result;
    }
```

Calling :

```
RequestPageAsync("www.xyz.com/aaa.html?search=aaa&id=1", "cachePath1", 1.0);
```